# Unable to create JSON correctly

Tags: java, json

I was trying with the following program

```
  package com;


import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {



}
```

I was successful until here

Which is producing jsom until leaf , from there on i am completely lost .

Comment: You seem to be producing valid JSON. What do you mean by "completely lost?"

Comment: @DavidEhrmann , I am unable to put the leafobj inside the t3data  , could you please help

Comment: can you give an example of your incorrect output json?

Comment: plz give me a minute , i will paste that

Comment: Rather than making JSON string from JSON object. Try it in reverse order it means create JSON object form JSON string that will help you to make it more clear.

Comment: I am new to this and also the Dead line is completed for this , so i dont know how much time it will take for me to understand that and implement it .

Comment: @MattCoubrough , i have edited my question explaining the issue , please see the updated question

Comment: Work from inside out, create the inner most structure, then "wrap" it with the surrounding structure.  It requires bas-ackwards thinking to a degree, but it's not that hard once you get over the mental block.

Comment: @HotLicks the creation of leaf is done , the problem is creating the t3 array itself .

Comment: One layer at a time.  Figure out how to create `{ "name": "Lemon","leaf": [ { "name": "500 ML" } ] }` and it's siblings, then worry about where they go.  Just be careful to not "reuse" an object from one to the next, since each object must be left unchanged until the whole structure is put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if in your implementation you are trying to accomplish this via a loop or recursion, but hardcoding the values into `JSONObject` you can accomplish the structure you are looking for with this:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject leaf = new JSONObject().put("name", "500 ML");
        JSONObject lemon = new JSONObject().put("name", "Lemon").put("leaf", new JSONArray().put(leaf));
        JSONObject orange = new JSONObject().put("name", "Orange").put("leaf", new JSONArray().put(leaf));
        JSONArray t3Array = new JSONArray().put(lemon).put(orange);
        JSONObject bottled = new JSONObject().put("name", "Bottled").put("T3", t3Array);
        JSONObject fountain = new JSONObject().put("name", "Fountain").put("T3", t3Array);
        JSONObject softDrink = new JSONObject().put("T2", new JSONArray().put(bottled).put(fountain));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject().put("Soft Drinks", softDrink);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i will try to use this in my code .

Comment: Np, if it's possible to include [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in your project it makes working with JSON somewhat easier.